# Scrapy do something before resume

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm using scrapy to crawl a web-site with authentication.
I want to be able to save the state of the crawler and I use

```
scrapy crawl myspider -s JOBDIR=mydir
```

After I resume with the same command I want to be able to login to the website **before** it **reschedules** all saved requests.

Basically, I want to be sure that my function `login()` and `after_login()` will be called before any other request is scheduled and executed. And I don't want to use cookies, because they don't allow me to pause the crawling for a long time.
I can call `login()` in `start_requests()`, but this works only when I run the crawler for the first time.

```py
class MyCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    # ...

    START_URLS = ['someurl.com', 'someurl2.com']
    LOGIN_PAGE = u'https://login_page.php'

    def login(self):
        return Request(url=self.LOGIN_PAGE, callback=self.login_email,
                      dont_filter=True, priority=9999)    

    def login_form(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                          formdata={'Email': 'myemail',
                                                    'Passwd': 'mypasswd'},
                                          callback=self.after_login, 
                                          dont_filter=True,
                                          priority=9999)

    def after_login(self, response):
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
        else:
            print("Login Successful!!")
            self.is_logged_in = True
            for url in self.START_URLS:
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_artists_json, dont_filter=True)
```

**Bottomline:** Is there any callback which will always be called when I resume crawling with `-s JOBDIR=...` option before rescheduling previous requests? I will use it to call `login()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `spider_opened` signal ([more here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-opened))

This function is intended to resource allocation for the spiders and others initializations, so it doesn't expect you to yield a Request object from there.

You can go around this by having an array of pending requests. This is needed because scrapy doesn't allow you to manually scheduled requests.

Then, after resume the spider you can queue the login as the first requests on the queue:

```
def spider_opened(self, spider):
    self.spider.requests.insert(0, self.spider.login())
```

You also need to add a `next_request` method into your spider

```
def next_request(self):
    if self.requests:
        yield self.requests.pop(0)
```

And queue all you requests by adding them to the `requests` array, and calling `next_request` add the end of each method:

```
def after_login(self, response):
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.logger.error("Login failed")
        return
    else:
        print("Login Successful!!")
        self.is_logged_in = True
        if not self.requests:
            for url in self.START_URLS:
                self.requests.append(Request(url, callback=self.parse_artists_json, dont_filter=True)

    yield self.next_request()
```

Comment: Thanks, @VMRuiz, I had momewhat similar solution. I checked that I'm not logged in yet and login was not scheduled and then I scheduled login  request in my parse methods. You solution is cleaner, but it doesn't solve the following **problem**:  On the moment when parse method will be called for the first time scheduler will already have a queue of requests which were restored from file. As scrapy works asynchronously it will send several requests before sending login.

Comment: Using this system, only one request can be scheduled at the sametime. Worst case  scenario, is that the scheduler will process the first pending request before try to log again. In that case, you could check if the requests failed because of the login and queue it again.